# Getting KeyError at login_user function view for member_id

Tags: python, django

```
def login_user(request):
    if request.session['member_id']:
        m=User.objects.get(id=request.session['member_id'])
        #state = "You're successfully logged in!"
        username = m.username
        return render(request,'auth/success.html',{'username': username})
    else:    
        state = "Please log in below..."
        username = password = ''
        if request.POST:
            username = request.POST.get('username')
            password = request.POST.get('password')

            user = authenticate(username=username, password=password)
            if user is not None:
                if user.is_active:
                    login(request, user)
                    m=User.objects.get(username=username)
                    state = "You're successfully logged in!"
                    request.session['member_id'] = m.id
                    return render(request,'auth/success.html',{'state':state, 'username': username})
                else:
                    state = "Your account is not active, please contact the site admin."
                    return render(request,'auth/auth.html',{'state':state, 'username': username})
            else:
                state = "Your username and/or password were incorrect."
                return render(request,'auth/auth.html',{'state':state, 'username': username})

        else:
            return render(request,'auth/auth.html',{'state':state, 'username': username})
```

My code is like above. Actually I want to check if member_id exists in session. But Getting KeyError at login_user function view for member_id

Answer (score 2):

You sould use the [`in` operator](http://kracekumar.com/post/22512660850/python-in-operator-use-cases):

```
if 'member_id' in request.session:
```

Note that, if it exists, but is "falsy" (`False`, `None`, `0`, `""` etc) the `in` operator will succeed, but `request.session['member_id']` will not be a valid `id`, so you might want to check for both:

```
if 'member_id' in request.session and request.session['member_id']:
```

Comment: Thanks mgibsonbr. I understand now.